# Existe como recuperar dados de um banco MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu dei um delete em alguns arquivos da tabela, tem alguma maneira de recuperar?
Ouvi falar sobre o "flashback", mas pelo pouco que pesquisei é somente para oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se tiveres os *logs* binários ativos, podes fazer uso do programa utilitário [`mysqlbinlog`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html)  para gerar um ficheiro SQL e depois abrir o mesmo e localizar os dados perdidos:

```
mysqlbinlog meuficheiroBinarioDeLog > minhaConsulta.sql
```

Tirando isto, só mesmo se tiveres backups das tuas base de dados.